# Catching Signals and Pausing with Character Device Drivers

Tags: c, linux, signals, linux-device-driver, daemon

I'm a student new to `C Programming` and am not fully understanding how signal catching works, and in line with character device drivers.  I'd appreciate some help but I need to state that this is for a project that is due in my first `C Programming` class.  So I have not posted any direct code, only an example of my initial approach.

My project needs to accept a signal input and set that signal to a variable to pass to my `character device driver`. Another program I've written will need to access that variable's value such that when read, it performs a certain outcome.  I've tried to run my control program (`<name> &`) but it quits immediately.  I double check by entering `ps` into my command prompt and the process is gone.

Basically I need my control program to pause and wait for the signal to be received.  Once received, if the signal matches it will set a variable to its value.  Otherwise, if it is `SIGTERM` it will either end or `pause()`, where it will wait until another signal is received that meets another condition.  Currently, when I compile and run it with `&` it simply runs and quits.  Here is an example of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int file_state;                    //variable to pass to the driver for recording

void sig_handler(int sig);        

void sig_handler(int sig){
    while(1){
        if(sig == SIGRTMIN){
            printf("SIG = SIGRTMIN\n");
            file_state = 0;
        }else if(sig == SIGRTMIN+1){
            printf("SIG = SIGRTMIN1\n");
            file_state = 1;
        }else if(sig == SIGTERM){
            printf("Exiting\n");
            exit(0);                         //exit
        }else{
            printf("SIG = %i\n", sig);
            pause();                        //doesn't match, pause for next signal
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
    //return 0;  //tried with and without
}
```

I'm waiting until this `daemon` receives a signal to put the `device driver` into a particular mode.  I haven't entered any `write()` methods yet because I'm trying to take this one step at a time where I send a signal with `kill()` and the proper response is returned with `printf()`. 
 My problem is that I can't seem to keep this in `pause()` mode while I'm waiting for a signal that breaks the `if` loop.  What's worse (other than my lack of knowledge and programming) is that I can't even keep this `daemon` open long enough to attempt a signal send.  Once I can get this to pause and receive the signal, I plan to use the system `write()` method to write my `file_state` variable to the `/dev/<filename>`, which will be cross-referenced in my executable.

How far off am I?  This is the final part that (I believe) I'm stuck on and I can't figure out how this should be approached.  I've looked online and about 95% of the examples that delve into this contain methods we haven't learned yet.  And if not, the examples are more simplistic where they do not include passing a value to a `character device driver` for use when another program is using the driver.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**ETA**
I've updated my code so now it stays open until a signal is received.  Problem is that I want this to `pause()` and remain open until the `SIGTERM` signal is received, breaking the loop and ending the program.  I can't seem to get the loop correct.  Even entering a conditional `int` variable into the `while()` loop still is broken when any signal is received.  Here is my updated code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int file_state;                    //variable to pass to the driver for recording

int keep_alive = 1;                       //added for conditional checking to keep the while 
                                          //loop open to receive more than one signal

void sig_handler(int sig);        

void sig_handler(int sig){
    if(sig == SIGRTMIN){
        printf("SIG = SIGRTMIN\n");
        file_state = 0;
    }else if(sig == SIGRTMIN+1){
        printf("SIG = SIGRTMIN1\n");
        file_state = 1;
    }else if(sig == SIGTERM){
        keep_alive = 0;                     
    }else{
    }
}

int main(){
    do{
        signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
        pause();                           //thought pausing here would help with waiting for a new signal
    }while(keep_alive == 1);               //keep looping until false
    return 0;                              //tried with and without
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a method to keep this process and signal catching loop alive until a specific signal is received.  I can't figure it out for the life of me.

**ETA 2**

Discovered my issue.  I wasn't paying attention and fully understanding the `signal()` method.  The first argument requires the exact signal you are attempting to catch.  I was using `SIGINT` which I was understanding it to be a "class" of interrupts that you wanted to catch.  And then in the `signal_handler()` function, you would specify which type of interrupt you were catching.  But, it is actually looking to catch the *exact* signal you are interested in.  So in my example code, I should have been using:

```
int main(){
    if(signal(SIGRMIN, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR){
         printf("can't catch SIGRMIN Signal.\n")
    }
...
}
```

I'm going to update with my new script as an answer and if anyone thinks it should be done differently or have any constructive criticisms please let me know.  Thanks again!

Comment: You can only safely call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler.  POSIX-mandated async-signal-safe functions can be found at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03  Note that `printf()` is **not** async-signal-safe.

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks for the link.  Honestly, my `printf()` calls are simply for me troubleshooting right now.  I did not know that detail about them, however.  I just wanted to make sure it was working and the process was not quitting after receiving the different signals.

Answer (score 1):

So I found my issue, and it is working now.  Below is my fixed code that produces the correct response back to the terminal when caught.  I've added a `for()` loop to catch any other signals I'm not worried about didn't stop my process, only `SIGTERM` will.  Look forward to getting critiqued and why I would never want to do my approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int file_state;                    //variable to pass to the driver for recording

void sig_handler(int sig);        

void sig_handler(int sig){
    if(sig == SIGRTMIN){
        printf("SIG = SIGRTMIN\n");
        file_state = 0;
    }else if(sig == SIGRTMIN+1){
        printf("SIG = SIGRTMIN1\n");
        file_state = 1;
    }else if(sig == SIGTERM){
        exit(0);
        EXIT_SUCCESS;                     
    }else{
        printf("SIGNAL CAUGHT #%d\n", sig);
    }
}

int main(){
    if(signal(SIGRTMIN, sig_handler)==SIG_ERR){
         printf("Unable to catch SIGRTMIN\n");
    }
    if(signal(SIGRTMIN+1, sig_handler)==SIG_ERR){
         printf("Unable to catch SIGRTMIN+1\n");
    }
    if(signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler)==SIG_ERR){
         printf("Unable to terminate process.\n");
    }

    //This for loop will catch all other signals except the un-catchable and
    //other user-specified above signal #31.

    int s;
    for(s = 0; s < 32; s++){
         signal(s, sig_handler);
    }

    while(1);
    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts, 1st user space where generation and catching of signals occurs. This has nothing to do with kernel driver. Your code seems okay about it.

2nd is interacting with driver when signal has been caught. For char driver have a look at this [link](http://opensourceforu.com/2011/02/linux-character-drivers/). You can simply write a value write(fd, 1, &buf); from user space program and implement corresponding write() in char driver.

Comment: I don't think I follow your response (thanks by the way).  If the code appears ok, why is it not pausing and staying open?  As soon as I run it, the process closes without any signals being sent to it.  And for your second point, can't I use the static variable across the files that are linked (process, driver, user program) based on the signal caught or should I write to the device driver and reference that value from my user program?

Comment: Kernel space driver and user space progress are two completely different things. They can interact via only interface (system calls) provided by linux kernel. So we need to have one C source file for user program and one C source file which will be our driver.

Comment: Oh yeah ok.  Yeah we actually are tasked with using three files.  One will be the signal controller which will send the function signal to my device driver (.ko extension and second file) and the third file is the application which will be reading from the device file.  I'm trying to capture the signals (without closing after a valid signal is received) and have the device driver provide my application with the correct output when read (again, depending on the signal caught).